# Electron how to show loading spinner while loading page in BrowserWindow

Tags: spinner, electron

I'm building an Electron Browser app. 
This app will load an external url (only)
My question is how to add a spinner (gif image) while loading the page.
I know that there is an even 'did-start-loadin'. this is working fine, but I did not find a way to show a runner.
Also there is not status bar option in Electron / BrowserWindow.
putting it there would be my favorite.

any ideas how to do that?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe create a second window that opens immediately after you start the app. Basically just a splash-screen with your spinner. Your main window should be hidden, while it's loading, but once `did-finish-load` fired, you can close the splash screen and show the main window.

Comment: That's what I already have. But this is only at starting the app. When submitting a page or loading another page I want this to be visible by the end user. So some loading indicator.

Comment: Maybe the [webview](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/webview-tag.md) element could be something for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for just a basic indication that webapp is loading some url content, this code may help. It changes the window's title and shows a progress bar (you may also change icon etc probably). After creating the main window:

```js
const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({ .... });      

mainWindow.webContents.on('did-start-loading', () => {
    mainWindow.setTitle(APP_NAME + ' * Loading ....');
    mainWindow.setProgressBar(2, { mode: 'indeterminate' }) // second parameter optional
});

mainWindow.webContents.on('did-stop-loading', () => {
    mainWindow.setTitle(APP_NAME);
    mainWindow.setProgressBar(-1);
});
```

If anyone can provide some means for animated title, happy to hear (probably some `setInterval`/`clearInterval` bundle, did not figure out yet).

Also can do `mainWindow.setOpacity(0.8)` on loading, but to me that does not look nice.